# Pusher Background Ionic 2

Tags: ionic2

Somebody know how Can I do a simple client (Pusher) on Ionic 2?
my server in node.js is like this:

```
var Pusher = require('pusher');

var pusher = new Pusher({
  appId: '261545',
  key: '3aa4f704a2e56f22dbc6',
  secret: '82729cfa5925e2c8785d',
  encrypted: true
});

pusher.trigger('test_channel', 'my_event', {
  "message": "hello world"
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Best regards.

Comment: Hi @Tecnico was you able to get it work? You are asking in your title for "Background" have you tried to get it work in background? I think this is not possible, but we are trying to do the same! Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

You must include the pusher.js in the bottom of your index.html (in your Ionic 2 app):

```
<script src="//js.pusher.com/3.2/pusher.min.js"></script>
```

Here you can find a simple quickstart: https://pusher.com/docs/javascript_quick_start